# Get items with conditional rendering based on their type

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There's List in which data in segregated based on their particular type

**Task to accomplish** :- display the only items of desired type.

```js
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
    items:{
        {
          type: "a",
          text: "TEXT A"
        },
        {
          type: "b",
          text: "TEXT B"
        },
        {
          type: "b",
          text: "TEXT B-1"
        },{
          type: "a",
          text: "TEXT A-2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div v-if="type == a">
    <div v-for="(item,key) in items">
      <p>{{item.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim can we do this in v-tabs???like placing the type in v-tabs and showing its text in v-tab-item ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REYgxN?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You should put a conditional rendering inside the `v-for` loop like :

```
<div >
  <div v-for="(item,key) in items">
  <p v-if="item.type == 'a'">{{item.text}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

or use a computed property called `itemsTypeA` and return only that items which their type == a and loop through that property inside your template  :

```
   computed:{
          itemsTypeA(){
              return this.items.filter(item=>{
              return item.type=='a'
              })
            }
        }
```

inside the template :

```
 <div >
  <div v-for="(item,key) in itemsTypeA">
  <p>{{item.text}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we do this in v-tabs???like placing the type in v-tabs and showing its text in v-tab-item ?